# Using jdk 1.6 and jdk 1.7 for different eclipse program

Tags: java, eclipse

i have two different Eclipse(Java EE and android) and two jdk(jdk6,jdk7)

i have confuse how to set java EE eclipse in jdk6 and android eclipse in jdk7

is this possible?

Comment: I could appreciate the confusion if you had to setup multiple versions of java in one instance of Eclipse. I can't in your case. Could you please explain what is it that you've tried which has not worked?

Answer (score 6):

You could set them in the *preferences*.

```
Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs
```

In this, you can add the `JREs` you want to use for the eclipse. Thus in your case, for Java EE eclipse, add the `JDK 1.6` and for `Android` eclipse, add the `JDK 1.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the answer of @R.J I would like to add that even if you don't have two separate eclipses.

You can use project specific settings and use different different JRE for different projects.

> Right click on Project --> Libraries ---> Remove JRE you dont want
>   ---> Add other JRE

Answer (score 0):

**Windows -> Preferences**

Then simply type jdk in the search box. Window is shown below. You can add your JDK here.

[image]